# Calling a shared code from Page method and WebApi Controller with Razor Pages

Tags: c#, linq, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using the new Razor Pages with core 2.0 and I'm trying to see if I can share the query code by putting the linq and db initialization into a Utility class in App_code folder but I'm having an issue with making this class to work.

Basically I'm querying the database with linq but I also have another asp-page-handler that will create a PDF.

Here is my page

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly CrewLogContext _context;
        //initialize db
        public IndexModel(CrewLogContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public IList<SelectionDailyReport> SelectionDailyReport { get; set; }
        public DateSearchRange DateSearchRange { get; set; }


 public async Task OnPostSelectionAsync(DateSearchRange DateSearchRange)
        {
            var result= await _context.TaskSelection.Where(x => x.WorkDate >= startDate && x.WorkDate <= endDate)
                .Include(t => t.Zone).OrderBy(x => x.AssocId).ToListAsync();

SelectionDailyReport = result;
}
```

OK. so this works fine. I also have a another button that calls a webApi controller that will basically query the same data and  generates a PDF as well.

I wanted to create a utility class and call its method from the page or the webapi controller so I don't have to write the linq query twice.

I created an App_Folder and add a .cs file

in Utility.cS

```
   namespace WebCrewLog.App_Code
    {
        public class Utility
        {
            private CrewLogContext _context;

            //initiate db connection
            public Utility(CrewLogContext context)
            {
               _context = context;
            }

            public  IList<SelectionDailyReport> GetSelectionData (DateSearchRange DateSearchRange)
            {
                var myList =  _context.TaskSelection.Where(x => x.WorkDate >=DateSearchRange.StartDate && x.WorkDate <= DateSearchRange.EndDate)
                    .Include(t => t.Zone).OrderBy(x => x.AssocId).ToList();
         return  myList ;
       }
```

Then from my page or my webapi I wanted to call

```
SelectionDailyReport = Utility.GetSelectionData(DateSearchRange);
```

So the problem is that intellisense does not detect the GetSelectionData method. So I thought I should make the GetSelectionData  method static.

so Change Utility Class

```
 public IList<SelectionDailyReport> GetSelectionData (DateSearchRange DateSearchRange)
        {
            var myList =  _context.TaskSelection.Where(x => x.WorkDate >=DateSearchRange.StartDate && x.WorkDate <= DateSearchRange.EndDate)
                .Include(t => t.Zone).OrderBy(x => x.AssocId).ToList();
....

 public  static IList<SelectionDailyReport> GetSelectionData (DateSearchRange DateSearchRange)
        {
            var myList =  _context.TaskSelection.Where(x => x.WorkDate >=DateSearchRange.StartDate && x.WorkDate <= DateSearchRange.EndDate)
                .Include(t => t.Zone).OrderBy(x => x.AssocId).ToList();
....
```

However, when I do that I'm getting a null exception on _context.TaskSelection and not sure why is that.

Comment: Because when you changed it to a static method, `_context` is not defined within the same method. You declared it in the constructor for Utility instance. Your previous attempt `Utility.GetSelectionData()` was making the call as a static method, but you wrote `.GetSelectionData` as an instance method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you changed the function to be `static`, now calling it does not initialize the class and the constructor `public Utility(CrewLogContext context)` is not called, so the `_context` field is not assigned to anything and stays `null`.

One way to solve this is to remove `static` and call the function after building the object and passing the context. So instead of:

```
SelectionDailyReport = Utility.GetSelectionData(DateSearchRange);
```

Try something like:

```
Utility u = new Utility(myContext); //Change myContext to the name of your context
SelectionDailyReport = u.GetSelectionData(DateSearchRange);
```

If you want it to be `static`, then you'll have to pass it the context:

```
public  static IList<SelectionDailyReport> GetSelectionData (DateSearchRange DateSearchRange, CrewLogContext context) {
    var myList =  context.TaskSelection.Where(x => x.WorkDate >=DateSearchRange.StartDate && x.WorkDate <= DateSearchRange.EndDate)
            .Include(t => t.Zone).OrderBy(x => x.AssocId).ToList();
     return  myList ;
   }
```

The above solutions may seem easier, but it's probably better to use the proper injection just like how it works in the controllers.